# Anyway to override/manipulate the Bookmark Page Action dialog box?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension that involves interacting with Chrome's bookmarks.

Is there anyway to either override the current Page Action dialog box for Bookmarks when you click on the star or is there anyway to change listing for the drop down of possible folders?

Barring that, is there a way to remove the star from the omnibar so that I can replace it with my own icon from my the extension?

Answer (score 0):

No to all questions unfortunately.
The best your going to get is to add your own page action next to the default.